# What are the default mappings for the up and down arrows keys in zsh

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I am trying to bind the default functionality of the up and down arrow keys in zsh to something else. I.e. Now when I press up, it basically shows me the previous command and when I press up again it shows me the command before that. I would like to bind this functionality to another key (say ^k and ^j). So the bind would look like:

```
bindkey '^k' up-line-or-history
bindkey '^j' down-line-or-history
```

However, I was searching around and found many possibilities: up-line, up-line-or-history etc. Which mappings are the default used by zsh for the up and down arrow keys ? I'm guessing its up-line-or-history and down-line-or-history but I can't be too sure.

Version:
**zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)**

Comment: As an alternative to mapping just in the shell, I use a utility (BetterTouchTool, at https://folivora.ai/ , though I'm sure others would work) to globally map `Fn`-i, `Fn`-j, `Fn`-k, and `Fn`-l to `up`, `left`, `down`, and `right`, so they're in roughly the same relative configuration as my actual arrow keys.

Comment: Thank goodness for this post. I screwed up my `^[[A` key binding and didn't want to restart my computer after commenting it out.

Comment: you can always resource your .zshrc or whichever file you are sourcing to pull in your keymaps. Or just run `exec zsh`, which reloads your whole zsh config except .zprofile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`up-line` is unbound by default; from `man zshzle`

> up-line (unbound) (unbound) (unbound)

which you can confirm by grepping for `up-line` in the output of `bindkeys`:

```
% bindkey | grep up-line
"^P" up-line-or-history
"^[OA" up-line-or-history
"^[[A" up-line-or-history
```

The documentation mentions that `up-line-history` is bound to `^P` and up-arrow:

> up-line-or-history (^P ESC-[A) (k) (ESC-[A)

Both `^[OA` and `^[[A` refer to the up-arrow key; I believe the duplication depends on your terminal emulator's settings, with the sequence generated by up-arrow depending on the "mode" of the terminal.